# Why does AFXMessageBox process other messages first?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, messagebox

I have a MFC dialog based application, with a thread that monitors a serial port connection. To keep things simple though, here I'm just simulating data being sent back to back in this example.

If I call Thread2() it will post three messages, and for the sake of example, lets say all three get posted before TestFunction() gets called once, which *is* what I'm seeing, but I don't think it will always occur that way.  Things worked great before I added an Afxmessagebox, but after, things got weird.

```
#define WM_TEST_MESSAGE WM_USER+9

bool ALERT_USER = true;

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDlg, CDialogEx)
  ON_MESSAGE(WM_TEST_MESSAGE, TestFunction)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// On thread 1
LRESULT CMyDlg::TestFunction(WPARAM ch, LPARAM port)
{
  TRACE("Before AFX\n");

  if (ALERT_USER)
  {
    AfxMessageBox("About to disable alert!");
    ALERT_USER = false;
  }

  TRACE("After AFX\n");

  return 0;
}

// On thread 2
void Thread2()
{
  ::PostMessage(port->m_pOwner->m_hWnd, WM_TEST_MESSAGE, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
  ::PostMessage(port->m_pOwner->m_hWnd, WM_TEST_MESSAGE, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
  ::PostMessage(port->m_pOwner->m_hWnd, WM_TEST_MESSAGE, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
}
```

This is what I expect to see:

```
Before AFX
About to disable alert!
After AFX
Before AFX
After AFX
Before AFX
After AFX
```

This is what I actually get:

```
Before AFX
Before AFX
Before AFX
About to disable alert!
After AFX
After AFX
After AFX
About to disable alert!
About to disable alert!
```

I found the best way to get my desired results is to swap the order of setting ALERT_USER to false with the message box, so that's not really an issue.

However, I really want to understand what is going on.  Stepping through the code, my best guess is that AFXMessageBox is forcing everything else through the message queue before it will run.

Can anyone explain what AfxMessageBox is doing behind the scenes?

Comment: It is modal and pumps a message loop.  You'll have to move the ALERT_USER = false; statement *before* the call.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a call to `AfxMessageBox`, it enters into message loop, and now `WndProc` can process new incoming messages. This is how MFC/Windows work - they keep on waiting for new messages (unless blocked). Note that displaying message box using `[Afx]MessageBox` is not blocking operation - it would rather enter into message-loop.

A `Sleep` call or a socket wait would be a blocking operation.

Comment: Some questions: "`[Afx]MessageBox` is not blocking" - does it mean the codes after `AfxMessageBox(...)` are executed while the user is seeing the popped-up message box? Also, why did you emphasize [Afx]? Is `MessageBox` a blocking operation?

Comment: @starriet 1. `AfxMessageBox` calls `MessageBox` Win32 API - no difference
2. Program code after the AMB will *not* be executed like that, but the message pump will still run. The message loop will handle mouse move, window close, okay button, F1 button, timer etc. But within the same thread. So when MB is called, the same thread may execute other parts via the message loop. This is how window messaging works for HWND!