# Calling (Afx)MessageBox in OnDraw

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, message-queue, messagebox

Let's say `OnDraw` calls a drawing function that calls `AfxMessageBox`:

```
void CmyprojectView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC) 
{
    myDraw(pDC);
}

myDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    // some code...

    AfxMessageBox(_T("First MessageBox"));

    // some code after the first AfxMessageBox...



    AfxMessageBox(_T("Second MessageBox"));

    // some code after the second AfxMessageBox...

}
```

As far as I know, `OnDraw` is called whenever `AfxMessageBox` is called.

Then what happens after the first `AfxMessageBox` gets called?
The `myDraw` runs again, and calls the first `AfxMessageBox` again? But if we run the above code, it executes as if a normal sequential flow (I think actually it's not, but it "looks like" that) - the first message box pops up, and if I hit 'ok', then the second message box pops up.

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36027541/10027592) by Ajay, when MessageBox is called, it's sent to the message loop, and the thread (that was running myDraw) processes other stuff. So, is the code after the first message box **not** executed before I click the 'ok' button in the message box?

Also, I'm confused about what happens when the second `AfxMessageBox` is called. `OnDraw` gets called again...? Then, when is the code after the *second* message box executed?

Please enlighten me with this message loop stuff :)

**EDIT)** Some context: I used `AfxMessageBox` in a function which is called by `OnDraw` just for debugging purpose (showing some values). But then I found that it triggers some strange behaviour and I noticed the execution flow is not simple. So I wondered what's going on. (This is just for learning, not for real application)

Comment: Very simple, when the message-box pops up and closed it invalidates a portion of the window, so this receives another `WM_PAINT` (mapped to `OnDraw()`) message.  Also, when the message-box is displayed (awaiting to click the OK or Cancel button) the application "yields", ie it is able of processing messages.

Comment: Launching a message box (either directly or through the `Afx` wrapper) spins up a "modal message loop", that won't return until the message box is dismissed. This message loop dispatches messages for your windows, so when the system decides that your window needs a `WM_PAINT` message, your window procedure is re-entered even before it has run to completion. I don't know whether MFC protects against re-entreacy, but even if it does doing anything but painting in a `WM_PAINT` handler is going to cause trouble.

Comment: Understanding how the system works is infinitely harder when using a framework on top of the system. You're likely going to understand things a lot easier if you removed MFC from the equation, until you are sufficiently familiar with the fundamentals.

Comment: Personally, I never display a message box in`OnDraw`.

Comment: Showing a message box in an OnDraw handler sounds like a very bad idea and poor design. Why do you need to do this? Give us some context information and explain why you need to show a message box in the OnDraw handler.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. You mean the message box's "nested" message loop, right? I tried to learn Win32API before I started MFC so I know how Win API is important so you're very right. Anyways, as you also mentioned, it's a quite complicated and bad idea to launch a message box in OnDraw, based on what I tested with my project.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It was a debugging purpose in a project for learning. You're right, it's a bad idea if one uses it in a real production :) I added some context following your advice, please have a look.

Comment: Use a debugger for debugging. [Log info to the Output window using tracepoints in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-tracepoints) explains how to do what you were trying to do in code.

Comment: Even stepping through draw code in a debugger causes issues when running on the same PC (remote debugging is more do-able).  Hence, I resort to "printf" debugging when this situation arises.  TRACE for debug builds, but you can also utilize OutputDebugString for release builds.

Comment: @franji1 We've had tracepoints literally for decades. It boggles the mind to think that developers are **still** making changes to their code solely for purposes of debugging output. That functionality is built into the debugger (including formatting), and does not require recompiling code, ever.

Comment: @IInspectable catch myself  doing this. It is because tracepoints, formatting is not trivial.  And get lost easily when you press twice F9.

Comment: @TomTom The format specifiers are listed here: [Format specifiers for C++ in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp).